Route organization in Actix web
I am trying to figure out a better way to organize the routes in my Actix application, the examples on actix.rs don't seem to have much on modularizing routes in other files. Currently I have something like this:
main.rs
HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .service(web::scope("/api").configure(routes::user::config))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8000))?
    .run()
    .await

routes/user.rs
pub fn config(cfg: &mut web::ServiceConfig) {
    cfg.service(
        web::resource("/user/login")
            .route(web::post().to(login))
    );
    cfg.service(
        web::resource("/user/{user_id}")
            .route(web::get().to(retrieve))
            .route(web::put().to(update))
    );
    cfg.service(
        web::resource("/user")
            .route(web::post().to(create))
    );
}

In user.rs I am calling cfg.service() for each different route, which is working, but seems less than ideal. I feel like I should maybe be able to use cfg.service() once for `/user', then nest the others in that somehow. However, I can't figure out how to do this.
Do I have to call cfg.service() for each individual route or is there a way to nest this? Or am I missing something and there is a much better way to handle/organize the routes?

You can create scopes for grouping routes under a common prefix. See also Scope in the documentation.

I've tried this, however, I cannot get it to work inside of cfg.service(). I might be missing something but it doesn't seem to work there for me.
